# How do I get the serving URL for Google Cloud Storage file objects on App Engine dev server?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have a python App Engine app and save files using the Google Cloud Storage API. However I need to get the serving URL for each file.

On production it is easy to figure out what the serving URL is as I prepend `http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com` to `/bucket/path/to/file.txt` as I already have the bucket name and path to my file.

How do I figure out what the serving URL is on the dev server?

It seems straight forward enough to do this with **images** using `images.get_serving_url` which can now take either blobstore or Cloud Storage references.

How can I figure out the serving URL for all files, not just images in a way that is compatible with both the development and production App Engine environments?

Comment: How are you storing objects in the development environment?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Still having the same question, 3 years later.

Comment: @SamBallantyne I never did. Hopefully things have changed since then!

Answer (score 2):

You can use GCS via the blobstore API. See this section for how to set up a serving handler for a GCS key:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Using_the_Blobstore_API_with_Google_Cloud_Storage

Comment: That's definitely an option but it requires more than 'figuring out' or deducing the serving URL like can be done in production. I would need to add my own request handler and make an RPC call to `blobstore.create_gs_key()`. Therefore the request would touch my App Engine instances and use up extra resources. I am looking for a solution such as replacing `http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com` with `http://localhost:8080/_ah/storage` for example. It seems a bit much to do all the above work just to get parity with development and production environments.

Comment: Is there a solution to access gcs on local appserver? I tried also the _ah/gcs in Java but it did not work.

Comment: Unfortunately the Java GCS Client Library uses the local Datastore / Blobstore [1] unlike the Python client, so a URL endpoint like _ah/gcs isn't available. Setting up your own serving handler is the only option available on dev. [1] https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-gcs-client/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/appengine/tools/cloudstorage/dev/LocalRawGcsService.java